# Divide by two a number in base -2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given this coding challenge when a applying for a summer internship but didn't get selected for the next round and I was curious if it could be improved.

The problem says:

> Given a number in base "-2" divide it by 2.
>
> For example:
>
> Given [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] (-23) the output is [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] (-11)
>
> Given [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] (-12) the output is [0, 1, 1, 1] (-6)
>
> **Note** the array is read from left to right. [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] = 1*(-2)^0 + 0*(-2)^1 + 0*(-2)^2 + 1*(-2)^3 + 1*(-2)^4 + 1 * (-2)^5 = 1
>   + 0 + 0 + (-8) + 16 + (-32) = -23

The easiest solution that I found was to convert the number to an integer, divide it by two and then convert it back to base -2.

Thanks in advance for your input.

My code in Python:

```
import math

# Main function
def solution(A):
    value = math.ceil(calculate_number(A) / 2)
    p = convert_number_to_binary(value)
    return p


# This function calculates the value of the list
def calculate_number(A):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, len(A)):
        total += A[i] * (-2) ** i
    return total

# This function converts a number to base -2
def convert_number_to_binary(number):
    binary = []
    if number == 0:
        return binary

    while number != 0:
        number, remainder = divmod(number, -2)
        if remainder < 0:
            number += 1
            remainder -= -2
        binary.append(remainder)
    return binary

print(solution([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: please add the context of how are you running the program

Comment: That is an arguably bad coding challenge for a summer internship; one wonders what signal they were attempting to extract from that challenge. Your solution seems quite straightforward; there are a few minor stylistic things I might change but the basic approach seems sound. I have given interview problems myself where the problem could be solved by transforming an unpleasant representation into a pleasant one, doing the work in the pleasant form, and then transforming back; it's a good technique that is applicable to real problems.

Comment: @EricLippert: Well, it tests if you understand the basic Python syntax, basic algorithms, know how to use functions and then if you know proper Python style. Not entirely useless IMO, depending on what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 6):

### General

- As per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions, the variables in functions should be in lowercase.
- Adding docstrings is recommended. [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
- Names should be short and meaningful. For example, `convert_number_to_binary` should actually be `to_base_minus_two`. Also, `calculate_number` should be `from_base_minus_two`
- Use [type hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5)
- Instead of `x == 0` python allows you to use use `not x`. Similarly, `x != 0` can be replaced with `x`.
- Envelop the main code inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`. This will prevent the code from being run if imported from another module.
- Following  @Martin R's advice, you can change -2 to a constant `BASE`

### Function `solution`

```py
value = math.ceil(from_base_minus_two(A) / 2)
p = to_base_minus_two(value)
return p
```

Can be replaced with the one liner:

```py
return to_base_minus_two(math.ceil(from_base_minus_two(a) / 2))
```

### Function `from_base_minus_two`

```
total = 0
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    total += a[i] * BASE ** i
return total
```

Instead, you can use:

```
return sum(j * BASE ** i for i, j in enumerate(a)))
```

### Function `to_base_minus_two`

The value you are finding isn't exactly `binary`. Change it to `base_minus_two`

You don't need to use

```py
if number == 0:
    return base_minus_two
```

Automatically, the while loop will terminate immediately as `number` is 0, and will return `base_minus_two` which is `[]`

---

Here's what the final code might look like:

```py
import math
from typing import List


BASE = -2


def from_base_minus_two(a: List[int]) -> int:
    """ Converts base 'BASE' to decimal """

    return sum(j * BASE ** i for i, j in enumerate(a))


def to_base_minus_two(number: int) -> List[int]:
    """ Converts decimal to 'BASE' """

    base_minus_two = []

    while number:
        number, remainder = divmod(number, BASE)

        if remainder < 0:
            number += 1
            remainder -= BASE

        base_minus_two.append(remainder)

    return base_minus_two


def solution(a: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """

    * Converts from 'BASE' to decimal
    * Divides the decimal by 2
    * Converts the decimal back to 'BASE'

    """

    return to_base_minus_two(math.ceil(from_base_minus_two(a) / 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(solution([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: Re *“remainder -= -2 can be replaced with remainder += 2”*: I'd prefer the original version because it emphasizes the connection to the base -2. (Or better, `remainder -= BASE` using a constant definition).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the idea. I've updated my code according to it

Answer (score 4):

#### A bug?

Here

```
value = math.ceil(calculate_number(A) / 2)
```

you use the `ceil` function, apparently to truncate the result dividing a negative number towards zero, so that, for example, `-23` becomes `-11`. But for positive odd numbers this gives an unexpected result:

```
print(solution([1, 1, 1])) # 1 - 2 + 4 = 3
```

returns `[0, 1, 1] = -2 + 4 = 2` where I would expect `[1] = 1`. If that line is replaced by

```
value = int(calculate_number(A) / 2)
```

then both positive and negative values are rounded towards zero. As a side-effect, the

```
import math
```

is not needed anymore.

#### Some small simplifications

The test

```
if number == 0:
    return binary
```

in `convert_number_to_binary()` is not needed: If the passed number is zero then the `while` loop will not execute.

The exponentiation in the conversion from binary to number can be avoided if the digits are processed in reverse order:

```
def calculate_number(A):
    total = 0
    for digit in reversed(A):
        total = (-2) * total + digit
    return total
```

And that can be compactly expressed as a [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) operation:

```
import functools

def calculate_number(binary):
    return functools.reduce(lambda total, digit: -2 * total + digit, reversed(binary))
```

Answer (score 3):

Python has [`docstring`s to document your functions properly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Just move your comments there, as a first step.

In the `calculate_number` function (which I would rename to `from_base_neg_2` or something similar) you can use a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (or even better, a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)):

```
def from_base_neg_2(A):
    """Calculate the value of a number in base -2,
       given as a list of coefficients, sorted from smallest exponent to largest.
    """
    return sum(a * (-2) ** i for i, a in enumerate(A))
```

Similarly, I would call the inverse function `to_base_neg_2` or something like it.

Your main calling code should be under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this module. Arguably the `solution` function should be defined last, since it depends on all the other functions and that makes it slightly easier to read.

```
def solution(A):
    """Main function.
    Divide A, a number in base -2, by 2.
    """
    return to_base_neg_2(math.ceil(from_base_neg_2(A) / 2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(solution([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]))
```